# Set default volume for bluetooth speakers upon connecting

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I am using bluetooth headphones on a Windows 10 computer.

The problem i am facing is that whenever the bluetooth headphones connect to the computer, their volume in the Windows Sound Settings is reset to 100%, disregarding the lower value i set the last time i used them. As i often forgot about that fact i regularly hurt my ears and hearing.

Is there a way to make Windows 10 set a lower "default" volume upon connecting to a bluetooth device or have it remember the value i set during previous connections? I have scoured through the system settings and Microsofts documentation but to no success.

Comment: Perhaps try updating both BlueTooth and Audio drivers.

Comment: Try to [Enable Bluetooth Absolute Volume](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/151957-how-enable-disable-bluetooth-absolute-volume-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. EarTrumpet
2. Own script

Option 1:
Download EarTrumpet from Microsoft store. After installing click settings. In Settings, you can adjust the default volume for individual audio devices, including your Bluetooth headphones.

Option 2:
Open any text editor. Use this code:

```
$DeviceName = *"Your Bluetooth Headphones Name"*
$DesiredVolume = 50

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class VolumeControl {
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint pdwVolume);
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);
}
'@

$audioDevices = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_SoundDevice"
$bluetoothDevice = $audioDevices | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $DeviceName}

if ($bluetoothDevice) {
    $volume = [math]::round(($DesiredVolume * 65535) / 100)
    [VolumeControl]::waveOutSetVolume([System.IntPtr]::Zero, $volume)
}
```

Replace *"Your Bluetooth Headphones Name"* with the exact name of your Bluetooth headphones as it appears in the Windows sound settings (keep the quotes around the name). Adjust the value of **$DesiredVolume** to your preferred volume level (0 to 100). Then save the file with a ".ps1" extension. Right-click on the saved file and click "Run with PowerShell" (You may need to run with admin rights).

But to make the script run automatically every time you connect your Bluetooth headphones, you can use Windows Task Scheduler to create a task that triggers Bluetooth device connection events.

To create a task in Windows Task Scheduler that triggers the PowerShell script when your Bluetooth headphones connect, follow these steps:

1. Press `Win + R` to open the Run dialog, type `taskschd.msc`, and press Enter to open Task Scheduler.
2. In the Task Scheduler window, click on "Task Scheduler Library" in the left pane.
3. Right-click in the middle pane and select "Create New Task" from the context menu.
4. In the "General" tab of the "Create Task" window, give your task a name (e.g., *"SetBluetoothHeadphoneVolume"*) and provide an optional description.
5. Click on the "Triggers" tab and the "New..." button.
6. In the "New Trigger" window, change the "Begin the task" dropdown menu to "On an event".
7. Configure the event trigger settings as follows:

   - Log: System
   - Source: BTHUSB
   - Event ID: 17 (Event ID 17 indicates a successful connection of a Bluetooth device)
8. Click "OK" to save the trigger.
9. Click the "Actions" tab and then the "New..." button.
10. In the "New Action" window, change the "Action" dropdown menu to "Start a program".
11. In the "Program/script" field, enter `powershell.exe`.
12. In the "Add arguments (optional)" field, enter the following:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File *"Full path to your PowerShell script"*
```

Replace "Full path to your PowerShell script" with the complete path to the ".ps1" file you created earlier, including the file name. For example:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\BluetoothVolume.ps1"
```

13. Click "OK" to save the action.
14. Optional: You can click on the "Conditions" and "Settings" tabs to customize your task.
15. Click "OK" to save and create the new task.

Task Scheduler will run your PowerShell script automatically whenever your Bluetooth headphones connect to your computer. It should work in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i run the script (even with admin rights and execution policy bypass) i get an error saying "'IntPtr' could not be found". Would you maybe know how to fix this error?

Comment: Also, i am already using EarTrumpet (Version 2.2.2.0), but for some reason the only settings i can change there are keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @WhiteMaple try to install Powershell Module. Open Powershell with admin rights, type ```Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets```. It will ask you something. Type Y and hit enter.

Then let's modify the script:

Import-Module AudioDeviceCmdlets

$DeviceName = "Your Bluetooth Headphones Name"
$DesiredVolume = 50

$audioDevices = Get-AudioDevice -List
$bluetoothDevice = $audioDevices | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $DeviceName }

if ($bluetoothDevice) {
    Set-AudioDevice -Index $bluetoothDevice.Index
    Set-AudioDeviceVolume -Volume $DesiredVolume
}